# Problems With StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I have to create a Number memory game, but if the user enters in the wrong numbers I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I have looked at many examples and still can't figure out how to fix it. This happens in the  `actionPerformed` method, with this line of code `newNumber = answer.substring(counterOne, counterTwo);` Any help would be very appreciated.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class MemoryGame extends Applet implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    private Label prompt;
    private Button button;
    private TextField input, numDisplay;
    private int arrayCounter = 3, backgroundColor =0; 
    private int[] myArray = new int[arrayCounter];
    private int[] compare = new int[arrayCounter];
    private Thread delayThread;
    private boolean running = true, isCompare; 


    public void init(){
        prompt = new Label("Enter the numbers!");
        input = new TextField(20);
        numDisplay = new TextField(20);
        numDisplay.setEditable(false);
        button = new Button("Enter");

        add(prompt);
        add(input);
        add(numDisplay);
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        populateArray();
        delayThread = new Thread(this); 
        delayThread.start();


    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        if(backgroundColor == 1){
            setBackground (Color.green);
        }
        else if(backgroundColor == 2){
            setBackground (Color.red);
        }
    }


    public void populateArray() {
        GenerateNumbers a = new GenerateNumbers();
        myArray = a.returnArray(); 


        int count = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println("index: " + count + " : " + myArray[i]);
            count++;
            numDisplay.setText(" ");
        } //for testing purpose
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        String answer ="", newNumber="";
        String[] stringArray = new String[arrayCounter];
        int counterOne = 0, counterTwo = 2;
        try{
            answer = input.getText();
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayCounter;i++){
                newNumber = answer.substring(counterOne, counterTwo);
                stringArray[i] = newNumber;
                counterOne += 3;
                counterTwo += 3;
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayCounter;i++){
            compare[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayCounter;i++){
            if(myArray[i] != compare[i]){
                backgroundColor = 2;
                input.setText("Wrong");
                repaint();
            }
            else{
                backgroundColor =1;
                input.setText("RIGHT!");//testing
                repaint();
            }

        }

    }

    public void destroy(){
        running = false; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            String numberString = "" ,stringTwo = "  ";
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayCounter;i++){
                numberString += myArray[i] + stringTwo;
                numDisplay.setText(numberString);
            }
            try{
                delayThread.sleep(3500);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            numDisplay.setText(" ");
            destroy();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you call `answer.substring(counterOne, counterTwo)`, you must make sure that `0 <= counterOne < answer.length()` and `counterTwo <= answer.length()`.

`substring` would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex`.

EDIT :

Let's try to fix your problems. The logic of the following loop is flawed :

```
        answer = input.getText();
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayCounter;i++){
            newNumber = answer.substring(counterOne, counterTwo);
            stringArray[i] = newNumber;
            counterOne += 3;
            counterTwo += 3;
        }
```

If I understood what you are trying to do, you are expecting the input String (stored is `answer`) to contain numbers, you create an array of these numbers, and compare it to the array of the correct numbers.

However, the above loop can only work if the user's answer begins with something like "11x22x33...", since you are expecting to extract `arrayCounter` (=3) substrings of 2 characters each from that input String, and you are extracting them from positions (0,1) (3,4) (6,7) of the String. This means that if the String is shorter than 8 characters, you'll be getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You shouldn't make assumptions on the length of the numbers, or the number of numbers in the input string. A better and simpler solution would be :

```
stringArray = answer.split(" ");
```

This would split the input array at the spaces. Note that the length of the array you will get won't necessarily match the length of the correct answer, so you'll have to compare the lengths.

Comment: Should we also check counterTwo is greater than counterOne ?

Comment: @StackFlowed Yes we should, but that's already taken care of in the OP's code, since counterOne is initialized to 0 and counterTwo to 2, and they are both incremented by 3 in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for this. And yes that is what i was trying to do  and had completely forgot that '.split' existed, i knew the logic was flawed(that i was making the assumption that the array would contain numbers in the format 11x22x33) but was unsure how to solve it. Thanks for the help and advice! @Eran

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` will occur - if any of the below conditions are met

```
`counterOne` is negative, or 
`counterTwo` is larger than the length of `answer`, or 
`counterOne` is larger than `counterTwo`.
```

before you do `answer.substring(counterOne, counterTwo)` you can do as below

```
if (counterOne >= 0 && counterTwo < answer.length && counterOne <= counterTwo)
```